# Doxygen does not generate automatic links in markdown code blocks

Tags: markdown, doxygen, code-documentation

Using doxygen 1.8.13, how can I get automatic links to be generated in markdown code?  For example, I have the following two file:

**test.h**

```
/**
 * Function foo.
 * This is a code snippet in markdown format:
 *
 *          foo("Hello World!!!");
 *
 *  This is a regular code snippet:
 *  \code
 *  foo("Hello World!!!");
 *  \endcode
 **/
 void foo(const char *hello);
```

And the following companion file:

**test.md**

```
# Markdown Test

This is a code snippet in markdown format:

    foo("Hello World!!!");

This is a regular code snippet:
\code
foo("Hello World!!!");
\endcode
```

The output that I have when running doxygen on these files look like this:

**test.h**
[image]

Notice how the second snippet has generated a link for the `foo`, but the first hasn't.

**test.md**

[image]

Notice how none of the snippets has generated a link for the `foo` function - also, the formatting is quite different.

**So the question**: is there a way to configure doxygen such that automatic links are generated in the code sections of markdown documents?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question.

- From what I see, doxygen will not properly highlight indented code blocks. It will format them as code, but will not attempt to guess the language of the code; This can be resolved in by using a fenced code block - which will be assumed to be in the same language of the file it is found in. This works as expected:

**foo.h**

````
/**
 * Function foo.
 * This does not work properly:
 *
 *          foo("Hello World!!!");
 *
 *  But this does:
 *  ```
 *  foo("Hello World!!!");
 *  ```
 **/
 void foo(const char *hello);
````

- When writing code samples in markdown files (`.md`), doxygen will not automatically guess the code language. The solution when hosting code examples in `.md` files was simply to specify the language. Thereafter, automatic links are properly generated:

**foo.md**

````
# Markdown Test

This does not work properly:

    foo("Hello World!!!");

But this does
```{cpp}
foo("Hello World!!!");
```
````